# Jquery Mobile 1.4.1 dynamic header

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova, ios7

I'm trying to append my header (`date-role=header`) dynamically in jquery mobile 1.4.1. I'm adding a button to the right side of it and I'm using `$('#page').trigger('pagecreate')` so that the header is recreated with the new button and has the jquery mobile styling. This worked in jquery mobile 1.3.2, but does not work in 1.4.1. I tried it with the new `enhanceWithin()` function and it still does not work. I also tried `$('#header').enhanceWithin()` and that did not work either. I understand the `trigger('create')` method has been deprecated, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get this to work with the new `enhanceWithin()` function

Comment: Strange, in the [1.4.1 documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/) it seems to be working fine in the demo. They are using jQuery 1.9.1 but I doubt that matters..can you share the code for when and how you create the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to insert toolbars in jQuery Mobile 1.4 is different, `.toolbar()` function should be called on header/footer inserted dynamically.

```
$("[data-role=header], [data-role=footer]").toolbar();
```

And then, page's height should be reset as toolbars add padding to page causing page to scroll.

```
$.mobile.resetActivePageHeight();
```

The `.trigger("pagecreate")` and `.trigger("create")` are deprecated and replaced with `.enhanceWithin()`. The new function should be called on *parent* div containing the dynamically add elements.